# routing app coverage file could not saved

Tags: ios, mapkit

I use iTunes connect to publish app with mapkit,

but error says Routing App Coverage File missing, I must upload it.

So I create a geojson from http://geojoson.io I draw a box around US.

save this file to hard drive and upload, still error, says geojson format isn't valid.

To make it valid, you must to correct the original geojson file to below:

```
{ "type": "MultiPolygon", 
"coordinates": [ 
       [[ [
          -125.15625000000001,
          32.24997445586331
        ],
        [
          -125.15625000000001,
          41.77131167976407
        ],
        [
          -106.171875,
          41.77131167976407
        ],
        [
          -106.171875,
          32.24997445586331
        ],
        [
          -125.15625000000001,
          32.24997445586331
        ]
] ]]
}
```

Note:You must replace 'polygon' with "mulipolygon" and add one more level of [];

This is original geojson from http://geojson.io

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -125.15625000000001,
          32.24997445586331
        ],
        [
          -125.15625000000001,
          41.77131167976407
        ],
        [
          -106.171875,
          41.77131167976407
        ],
        [
          -106.171875,
          32.24997445586331
        ],
        [
          -125.15625000000001,
          32.24997445586331
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
}
]
}
```

Now I upload, it says it is a valid geojson routing file,

but another error says"routing app coverage file could not saved" please contact us.

who knows why?

Answer (score 0):

I temporarily work around of this problem by bypass Routing App Coverage File.

This is what you do:

in xcode, general -- capability --- maps (section), turn maps off
[image: turn off map capability]

re-upload to app store by,

Befor re-load, you need to modify build number different from last, also the release version (for example 1.0.1, should different from last time)

Otherwise, it will conflict with last build, app store will not accept it.

after

menu - product - archive upload to app store